# range Symfony form input

Tags: php, symfony

I'm looking for something to make this kind of input in Symfony:

[image: sample]

I don't know which kind of input and how to deal with the Symfony controller.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($newLot)
        ->add('lotType',null,['required' => false])
        ->add('lotGenre',null,['required' => false])
        ->add('ville',null)
        ->add('quartier',null)
        ->add('prix',null,['required' => false])
        ->add('prix', null,['required' => false])
        ->add('superficie', RangeType::class,['required' => false])
        ->add('createdAt', RangeType::class,['required' => false])
        ->add('gestionnaire',null)
        ->add('lotStatut',null)
        ->getForm();
```

Here is a part of my controller but not sure it's useful.

Comment: This is a UX design thing. You can't render an input like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to represent a start date linked to an end date, I'd advise you to create two [DateType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html) fields, like this:

```
->add('startDate', DateType::class, [some_parameters])
->add('endDate', DateType::class, [some_parameters])
```

Then, you design your two fields in your template, by adding the "à" cell between them.

The RangeType is not appropriate to render dates, it renders [this kind](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php) of input.